# Simple python to run as docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have very simple python script that accepts 2 numbers and print the sum of them. Lets call this script addNumbers.py
so if I use python to run the script I'll call it like this:

```
python3 addNumbers.py 10 20
```

I want to dockrize the simple script and call it via exec
I also want to keep the container up and running after starting it.
I have the following:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3" , "addNumbers.py"]
```

The thing is when I start the container I need to supply 2 numbers and then the container stops. I dont wnat to supply any numbers when first running the container and also  I want it to keep running and call it smothing like this:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> someNumber, otherNumber
```

Comment: Why do you need to start the container before you are ready to run the Python script?

Comment: if you want to run without arguments then you have to change Python code and remove part which expect values from command line. And if you want to keep it running then you have to use some loop like `while True` in Python code.